vlook up and match function in google sheet on html table extract
I am using importhtml in google sheet to fetch specific column values based on the dynamic URL.
Below is the import html formula in
D2 = IFERROR(INDEX(IMPORTHTML($B2,"table",1),2,10),"")
D3 = =IFERROR(INDEX(IMPORTHTML($C3,"table",1),2,9),"")
The problem is

I have to manually change column reference for D2 onwards from 10 to 11, 12...and for D3 onwards from 9 to 10, 11 because the column references are not matching based on month for different companies.
If the value shows null basis the URL1, i am changing to URL2, for D3, it shows null, so changed to C3

So I need some help to fix

The column value to pick based month updated in the column header
If the URL1 shows null value, use the URL2.




Company
URL 1
URL 2
Sep-2023
Dec-2024
Mar-2024
Jun-2024
Sep-2024




HCLTECH
https://www.screener.in/company/HCLTECH/consolidated/
https://www.screener.in/company/HCLTECH/
26,672
28,446
28,499
28,057
28,862


AAATECH
https://www.screener.in/company/AAATECH/consolidated/
https://www.screener.in/company/AAATECH/
5.5
5.5
9.4
3.6
4.4





You may try with this single formula(goes into Cell_D2) & applies to all of the given date range D1:H1:
=let(Σ,importhtml(B2,"table",),
 arrayformula(xlookup(D1:H1,chooserows(Σ,1),chooserows(Σ,2),"-")))



I have tried, i am getting null values, also how can I make the html link variable to work if B2 results null, it picks the url from C2.
